# Controlar fecha entre cliente y servidor en PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql, datetime

He realizado un pequeño módulo de registro de evento, teniendo entre su formulario campos de fecha y hora: `YY-mm-dd H:i:s`. Los usuarios que realizan el registro pueden ser de diferentes zonas horarias. Entonces un evento pautado para un momento no podría corresponder con los otros clientes.

Básicamente la preguntaría sería: ¿cómo convertir datos de "fecha y hora" en "zona horaria del cliente" a "zona horaria servidor" para guardar en BD.

Y viceversa: ¿cómo convertir datos de "fecha y hora" en "zona horaria servidor" a "zona horaria cliente"?

Utilizo un servidor de bases de datos Mysql.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Las fechas en bases de datos deben estar siempre en [UTC (Tiempo Universal Coordinado)](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiempo_universal_coordinado) o en [marca de tiempo UNIX](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marca_temporal) (UNIX timestamp, independiente de la franja horaria) y convertirse a horario local o bien en el lado del cliente usando javascript o bien en el lado del servidor usando, en tu caso, PHP.

## Usando PHP

PHP provee las herramientas necesarias para convertir fechas o marcas de hora a formato local:

- [`time()`](http://php.net/time): Obtiene una marca de tiempo UNIX.
- [`date_default_timezone_set()`](http://php.net/date-default-timezone-set): establece la franja horaria local con la que trabajan las siguientes funciones.
- [`date()`](http://php.net/date): convierte la fecha local actual o la marca de tiempo UNIX a una cadena con el formato deseado.
- [`setlocale()`](http://php.net/setlocale): establece la configuración local de idioma para fechas, números, etc.
- [`strftime()`](http://php.net/strftime): convierte la fecha local actual o la marca de tiempo UNIX a una cadena con el formato deseado con soporte para idiomas locales en nombre de meses, días, etc.

Básicamente lo que tienes que hacer es decidir si almacenas en tu base de datos marcas de tiempo UNIX o fechas y horas en UTC. Una vez decidido podrás hacer uso de `date()` y/o `strftime()` para mostrar dichas fechas en el lenguaje y franja horaria del usuario (puedes obtenerla a través de javascript en la pantalla de inicio de sesión, por poner un ejemplo) o bien la estática definida en tu servidor (en el `php.ini`) o bien programada en código.

Ejemplo:

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Madrid');
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'es_ES.utf8', 'es_ES@UTF8', 'es_ES', 'es');
/* 2013-01-09T02:53:20+00:00 en ISO-8601 */
$tiempo = 1357700000;
echo strftime("En España era el %A %e de %B de %Y a las %H horas, %M minutos y %S segundos", $tiempo), PHP_EOL;
date_default_timezone_set('America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires');
echo strftime("En Argentina (Buenos Aires) era el %A %e de %B de %Y a las %H horas, %M minutos y %S segundos", $tiempo), PHP_EOL;
```

Resultado de la ejecución:

> En España era el miércoles  9 de enero de 2013 a las 03 horas, 53 minutos y 20 segundos
>
> En Argentina (Buenos Aires) era el martes  8 de enero de 2013 a las 23 horas, 53 minutos y 20 segundos

## Usando Javascript

Javascript tiene un soporte básico para formato de fechas locales y de manera nativa únicamente gestiona la franja horaria.

Para crear una fecha [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Date) Javascript a partir de una marca de tiempo UNIX hay que multiplicar ésta por 100:

```js
function timestamp2cadena(timestamp){
  var date = new Date(timestamp * 1000);
  var meses = [
    'enero',
    'febrero',
    'marzo',
    'abril',
    'mayo',
    'junio',
    'julio',
    'agosto',
    'septiembre',
    'octubre',
    'noviembre',
    'diciembre'
  ];
  var año = date.getFullYear();
  var mes = meses[date.getMonth()];
  var día = date.getDate();
  var hora = date.getHours();
  var minutos = date.getMinutes();
  var segundos = date.getSeconds();
  return 'En horario local del navegador era el ' +
    día + ' de ' + mes + ' de ' + año + ' a las ' + hora + ' horas, ' + minutos + ' minutos y ' + segundos + ' segundos';
}
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  /* 2013-01-09T02:53:20+00:00 en ISO-8601 */
  document.getElementById('resultado').innerText = timestamp2cadena(1357700000);
});
```

```html
<p id="resultado">A rellenar por javascript</p>
```

El resultado en mi navegador (estando en España) es:

> En horario local del navegador era el 9 de enero de 2013 a las 3 horas, 53 minutos y 20 segundos

## Usando MySQL

MySQL también soporta gestionar franjas horarias y convertir fechas a diferentes locales aunque se necesita [un paso adicional](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/time-zone-support.html#time-zone-installation) que permite gestionar, por ejemplo, los horarios de invierno/verano.

Este ejemplo muestra cómo se puede convertir una fecha entre diferentes horas (sin tener en cuenta horario de verano):

```
CREATE TABLE pruebas (
  timestamp INT
);
SET time_zone = '+00:00'; -- Introducimos las fechas en UTC
INSERT INTO pruebas (timestamp) VALUES (
  1357700000
), ( -- Año no bisiesto, el día anterior es el 28 de febrero
  UNIX_TIMESTAMP(STR_TO_DATE('2018-03-01 02:56:23', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%S'))
), ( -- Año bisiesto, el día anterior es 29 de febrero
  UNIX_TIMESTAMP(STR_TO_DATE('2012-03-01 00:12:46', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%S'))
);
SET time_zone = '+01:00'; -- Franja actual de Madrid
SELECT timestamp, FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp) fecha FROM pruebas;
SET time_zone = '-03:00'; -- Franja actual de Buenos Aires
SELECT timestamp, FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp) fecha FROM pruebas;
```

Puedes ver el ejemplo funcionando en línea [pulsando aquí](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jkr3AHKzLK4pZUTiumjM4z/0).

Resultado:

```
timestamp   fecha
1357700000  2013-01-09 03:53:20
1519872983  2018-03-01 03:56:23
1330560766  2012-03-01 01:12:46

timestamp   fecha
1357700000  2013-01-08 23:53:20
1519872983  2018-02-28 23:56:23
1330560766  2012-02-29 21:12:46
```

Comment: Excelente información, para el timestamp de la base de datos, no tendría problemas en colocar un tipo de dato BIGINT o TIMESTAMP ?

Comment: Para un UNIX timestamp sería suficiente con un campo de tipo INT hasta el próximo martes 19 de enero de 2038 a las 4:14:07 (GMT+01:00). Si lo usas sin signo entonces podrías llegar al domingo 7 de febrero de 2106 a las 7:28:15 (GMT+01:00). Yo, personalmente, uso campos `DATETIME` que tienen un rango mayor y más preciso: del `0000-01-01 00:00:00` (el manual pone erróneamente `1000-01-01 00:00:00`) al `9999-12-31 23:59:59.999999`. MySQL provee un mecanismo con `TIMESTAMP` de conversión a UTC cuando guarda y de vuelta a local cuando las obtienes. Yo prefiero gestionar eso en mi aplicación.